Which 7zip to install with Homebrew on Mac?
I'm trying to install the 7zip tool using Homebrew on macOS, but when I run brew search 7zip, it outputs three different formulae, "7zip", "7-zip", and "p7zip". Which one is the official one?

If David's answer helped you please Check His answer as the Chosen answer. I like the name you chose, Twinkle Toes ;)

All three of them are implementations of the 7z compression algorithm, of which Igor Pavlov's 7-zip is probably the most well-known of.
Igor Pavlov's version is both 7-zip and 7zip. Both refer to the same package/homebrew script.
This can be verified with brew info. The From: entry in both cases points to https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/s/sevenzip.rb, as does the link to the homepage https://7-zip.org.
The p7zip executable is an implementation of the 7z compression algorithm with some extras sprinkled in, as documented on their github page https://github.com/p7zip-project/p7zip.

AFAIK, 7-Zip only has a console version for macOS. You do not need Homebrew to get the executable. You can download from here. The download contains the 7zz command and documentation.
